# Counting Divide-by-Zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I can easily count number of *#N/A*'s in a column with the array formula:

```
=SUM(--ISNA(A:A))
```

[image]

How would I count the number of *#DIV/0!*'s in a column **??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `=COUNTIF(A3:A10,"#DIV/0!")`

Source: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-errors.html